# DNS cannot resolve a web site address

Tags: networking, dns, adsl

I cannot seem to access one particular website while all others I have no problem. The website in question is **bbc.co.uk**.

At first, I thought there might be some problem with my laptop. However, if I use my laptop through my company network, I can load the page **bbc.co.uk** normally.

I then thought that maybe my ADSL at home might be blocking that web address. But I tried another laptop with my home ADSL and it can load the page **bbc.co.uk** very fast.

I am using Windows XP SP3, and I have tried to access the using IE, FireFox and Chrome and none of these work.

I have tried Aaron Digulla's suggestions, results of which are:

```
nslookup bbc.co.uk -> DNS request timed out. time out was two (2) seconds 
ping bbc.co.uk -> timed out 
telnet bbc.co.uk 80 -> timed out
```

Don't know what could be the problem. Can anyone tell me please?

Comment: If you *ping bbc.co.uk* what output do you see?

Comment: have you tried a different browser on the troubled computer?

Comment: Windows, Linux or MacOS?

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? What happens when you access the page (which error message)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these commands from the command line:

```
nslookup bbc.co.uk
ping bbc.co.uk
telnet bbc.co.uk 80
```

The first command checks whether your computer can resolve the name.

The second command checks whether the routing is set up correctly (i.e. packets can travel between your computer and the server). Note that not all servers allow `ping`. If in doubt, try with `www.google.com`.

The last command opens a connection to the web service on `bbc.co.uk` (port 80). If ping works but this doesn't, then the web service is down.

If you can resolve the name but neither ping nor telnet work, then you should check the routing and your firewall settings. Routing should be setup automatically when you connect your computer to your network via DHCP. Restart the ADSL router and then your computer.

If telnet works but your browser can't connect, check your proxy settings.

**[EDIT]** It seems you're using Windows and your DNS setup is broken. [See this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-out-what-my-dns-servers-address-is/) how to check your DNS settings. Compare them between your good and broken laptop.

Comment: BBC does respond to ping.

Comment: @Martin: I mentioned it because ping isn't reliable. There might a firewall in your way, for example.

Comment: Fair enough! A good set of troubleshooting steps as well.